# Excel ISERROR Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

been stuck on this but cant work out a solution.
I essentially need this line to work but also with the IFERROR function.

```
=SUM(IF(Waste=$E$3,Waste[Cost],0))
```

I do not see why this wouldn't work so think i may just be wording it wrong. (I remembered to do ctrl + shift + enter so it is definitely an array)
So essentially this line searches a table called **Waste** to find the name of a product that you enter into E3. For example:

```
     A        B       C         D          E
1 product| Cost  |         |         |
  -----------------------------------------------
2 beef   | 56    |         |         |
3 chicken| 10    |         |         |chicken
4 pork   | 66    |         |         |  28
5 chicken| 18    |         |         |
```

So for example if you typed **chicken** into D3 it would add up all of Cost when product = chicken, so this would return 28. The actual data i need it on can sometimes have errors which are fine as they are temporary but this function will be required to work at all times ignoring the errors.

These are some versions of this line i have tried, though these did not work.

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(Waste=$eE$3),0,Waste[Cost]))

=SUM(IF(ISERROR(Waste=$E$3,0,Waste[Cost])))

=SUM(IF(ISERROR(Waste=$E$3), Waste[Cost], 0))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try ...Waste[Product]=$e$3... Plus, it's always useful to use the evaluate formula function in Excel in such cases.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, both work perfectly. Thought I had tried Waste[Product] but i guess not. 
Seems unusual though as the original line i used that fails on errors was able to search the table and retrieve the correct data when there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to test the value of a cell `E3` against an entire table `Waste`. `Waste=E3` is nonsense as a table can't be equal to a single value.

Instead, just use the `=SUMIF()` formula:

```
=SUMIF(Waste[product], $E$3, Waste[Cost])
```

[image]